# best zip compression in shell script?

Tags: macos, zip

I run a bash script to compress several folders on my hard-disk by using build in zip program of macosX. But even with a call like `zip -rqy -9 myzip.zip myfolder` I get a pretty bad compression ratio compared to a zip created by the zip-function of the finder-application.

Does anyone can give me a hint, how get a much better compression ratio? (but I definitely need a zip file)

Comment: What kind of files are you trying to compile? With which algorithm?

Comment: Can you get better compression by any manual method, using either any GUI based zip tool or by command line? Then you can add it in the script.

Comment: I use a shell-script in Jenkins CI to automaticly create an zip-file containing the "binaries of my product", "example codes" and "automaticly generated user-documentation", in pre-build-phase.
Cause of its part of a automated build process, I dont want to call any gui-based applications.

Comment: Does it have to be `.zip` or can you use `.gzip`,`.bzip2` or `.7z`  archives ?